# How to make the path a variable in react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Like I have   `/a/Star/video`

I want to make the `video` a variable, `star` is already a param. How to do it? I need to know is, When video is provided, I need to render one component and when it is not provided, I want to render another component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested routes and an `<IndexRoute>` to handle this:

```
<Route path='/a/:param1' component={Root}>
  <IndexRoute component={OnlyParam1} />
  <Route path='video' component={WithVideo} />
</Route>
```

Comment: what is the difference between root component and onlyparam1 component?

Comment: `<Root>` will be the parent component of both `<OnlyParam1>` and `<WithVideo>`. You can render anything shared by those components in `<Root>` if you want or just have it render `this.props.children`.

Comment: can I remove root component and make onlyParam1 and WithVideo as two separate components ?

Comment: I believe that you need the `<Root>` component, but it can be a stateless component: `const Root = ({children}) => children`.